# How can I use Solana with Flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I use Solana with Flutter. İf you know please explain me. Because ı have a project and ı should use this

Answer (score 4):

To use Solana with Flutter, you can use the solana_sdk library, which provides a Dart interface to the Solana blockchain.

Here's an example of how you can use the solana_sdk library to send a transaction to the Solana blockchain from a Flutter app:

import 'package:solana_sdk/solana_sdk.dart';

// Replace with your own private key and Solana account
final privateKey = PrivateKey.fromHex(
'1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111',
);
final account = Account(
pubkey: privateKey.publicKey,
lamports: 50,
);

// Create a client for the desired Solana cluster
final client = Client(
clusterUrl: 'https://api.solana.com',
);

// Build a transfer transaction
final transferTransaction = TransferTransaction(
address: Address(
'1111111111111111111111111111111111111111',
),
amount: 10,
);

// Sign the transaction
final signature = transferTransaction.sign(privateKey);

// Submit the transaction to the network
final result = await client.submitTransaction(
transaction: transferTransaction,
signature: signature,
);

// Check the result of the transaction submission
if (result.isSuccess) {
print('Transaction was successful!');
} else {
print('Transaction failed: ${result.error}');
}

This example shows how to create a transfer transaction, sign it with a private key, and submit it to the Solana network. You can modify the example to perform other actions on the Solana blockchain, such as deploying and calling smart contracts.

I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 3):

The [Espresso Cash](https://www.espressocash.com/) team built and maintains a [Flutter Solana SDK](https://github.com/espresso-cash/espresso-cash-public/tree/master) that includes:

- [Mobile Wallet Adapter](https://github.com/espresso-cash/espresso-cash-public/tree/master/packages/solana_mobile_client) for signing txs/messages.
- Flutter [solana](https://github.com/espresso-cash/espresso-cash-public/tree/master/packages/solana) and [jsonrpc_client](https://github.com/espresso-cash/espresso-cash-public/tree/master/packages/jsonrpc_client) libraries for constructing transactions and submitting to RPCs.
- [solana_seed_vault](https://github.com/espresso-cash/espresso-cash-public/tree/master/packages/solana_seed_vault) for Seed Vault SDK

A good starting point is their [example app](https://github.com/espresso-cash/espresso-cash-public/tree/master/packages/solana_mobile_client/example) and the Solana Dart/Flutter dev discord mentioned [here](https://docs.solanamobile.com/additional-sdks/flutter_sdk).

Comment: This is the best answer here. I'm using these packages (excluding seed vault) and they're enabling our development fully! Antonie make sure your affiliation with Espresso Cash is disclosed, as per stackexchange TOS 

Answer (score 2):

Hey maybe you can use this:

https://pub.dev/packages/solana_web3

I have been using this library and so far it seems to me that it is complete to do things with the current version of solana to date.

Answer (score 1):

To use Solana with Flutter, you will first need to install the web3flutter package and import it into your Flutter project. Then, you can use the Web3 Flutter API to create a connection to the Solana blockchain, sign transactions, and interact with smart contracts.

Here is an example of how you might use Solana with Flutter to sign and send a transaction:
import 'package:web3flutter/web3flutter.dart';

void main() async {
// Connect to the Solana blockchain
var web3 = Web3('https://testnet.solana.com');

// Generate a new private key and account address
var privateKey = await web3.eth.accounts.create();
var fromAddress = privateKey.address;

// Construct the transaction data
var toAddress = '0x...'; // address of the recipient
var value = BigInt.from(1); // amount to send

// Sign the transaction
var signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
privateKey: privateKey,
to: toAddress,
value: value,
);

// Send the signed transaction
await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction);
}
This is just a simple example, and there are many other ways that you can use Solana with Flutter, depending on your specific needs. For more information and examples, you can refer to the web3flutter documentation and the Solana Web3 API documentation.